# How to detect which Bootstrap version is used from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, versioning

I've been looking at the [CSS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/dist/css) & [JavaScript](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap.js) from Bootstrap 3. Nothing is modularized under a common alias. For the JavaScript, it is injected into jQuery's prototype...

How would it be possible to detect which version of Bootstrap is included in a user's web page from a third party plugin/library point of view with JavaScript?

Comment: You want to detect it with JavaScript?

Comment: Well, as Bootstrap isn't name spaced, but rather a method-by-method implementation - would checking for a `typeof` function that's only available in `3.0.*` (and not in `2.3.*`) be sufficient?

Comment: @putvande: Personally, yes I would want to detect it with JavaScript.

Comment: @MackieeE: Would this mean having to do a typeof of a functionality until you find one? This could be more of a workaround for now.

Comment: Just for future reference: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12394.

Comment: Another issue for further reference: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12395.

Answer (score 49):

The version of each of Bootstrap's jQuery plugins can be accessed via the VERSION property of the plugin's constructor

```
$.fn.tooltip.Constructor.VERSION
```

Comment: This needs more upvotes I think. Any issues with this approach?

Comment: In some of my cases, `$.fn.tooltip.Constructor undefined` or `$.fn.tooltip undefined`, are there any solutions for these?

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in comments, the only `function` that seems to be *removed* in Bootstrap 3 was `typehead`, even then - there doesn't seem to be a reliable way of detecting which Bootstrap version the site has loaded.

```
var bsVersion = ( typeof $.fn.typeahead !== 'undefined' ? '2.3.2' : '3.0.0' );
```

Comment: You will get a false positive if a different library uses typeahead like Twitter Typeahead (which is different from the deprecated Twitter Bootstrap typeahead)

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to grab the *Bootstrap's version* based on its comments in *CSS* file, you could use the following code. It's been tested, to make sure it works.

Assume, that [`Bootstrap's CSS file`](http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css) contains a comment displaying a version (it always does actually):

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.0.3 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2013 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 */
```

Remember about [*same origin policy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), when using [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) method, where the request will not be successfully executed, if data-source is from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

```
$(function () {
    $.get("dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", function (data) {
        var version = data.match(/v[.\d]+[.\d]/);
        alert(version);
    });
});
```

[Example Online](http://jsfiddle.net/86DpF/)

> The online example above, is based on grabbing local file from *jsfiddle.net* but not from *getbootstrap.com*, because of the security reasons that were already mentioned, and extracting a comment, which should display accordingly after you hit
>   *Run* button.

You could also test it just by going to [`getbootstrap.com`](http://getbootstrap.com/), opening a console and pasting the code. After you run it, **you will get the current version of *Bootstrap* displayed**, which is ***v3.0.3*** at the moment.

Comment: this won't work on an app which minifies and precompiles assets say like a rails app.

Answer (score 1):

I share my Javascript Module :

```js
/**
 * Created by LJT.
 */
myBootstrapUtils = function () {

    /**
     * Search bootstrap.min.js or bootstrap.js in DOM
     * @return {*}
     */
    function getBootStrapJsUrl() {
        var bootstrapUrl;
        $('script').each(function () {
            var externalJsSrc = $(this).attr('src');
            if (typeof externalJsSrc !== 'undefined') {
                if (externalJsSrc.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf('bootstrap.min.js') !== -1 || externalJsSrc.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf('bootstrap.js') !== -1) {
                    bootstrapUrl = externalJsSrc;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        return bootstrapUrl;
    }

    function hasBootStrapJs() {
        return getBootStrapJsUrl() !== undefined;
    }


    /**
     * This function grab the bootstrap's version in Js File
     * @param data Data file representation
     * @return {*}
     */
    function analyseBootstrapJsFile(data) {
        var bootstrapVersion;
        var matches = data.match(/v[.\d]+[.\d]/);
        if (matches === null) {
            bootstrapVersion = 'unknown';
        } else {
            //Security Array.isArray(matches) === true ?
            bootstrapVersion = matches[0];
        }
        //console.log(bootstrapVersion);
        return bootstrapVersion;
    }


    function getBootStrapJsVersionSyncMode() {
        var version,
            bootstrapUrl = getBootStrapJsUrl();
        if (bootstrapUrl !== undefined) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: bootstrapUrl,
                success: function (data) {
                    version = analyseBootstrapJsFile(data);
                },
                async: false
            });
        }
        return version;
    }

    function getBootStrapJsVersionAsyncMode(defered) {
        var bootstrapUrl = getBootStrapJsUrl();
        if (bootstrapUrl !== undefined) {
            $.get(bootstrapUrl)
                .then(function (data) {
                    version = analyseBootstrapJsFile(data);
                    defered.resolve(version);
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    defered.fail();
                });
        } else {
            defered.fail();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Example for async mode usage
     */
    function exampleAsyncMode() {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        dfd.done(function (version) {
            console.log('My bootstrap version is : ' + version);
        });
        dfd.fail(function (version) {
            console.log('Error while request bootstrap version ...');
        });
        getBootStrapJsVersionAsyncMode(dfd);
    }

    /**
     * Easy way to get bootstrap plugin version
     * @see http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-version-nums
     * @return {*}
     */
    function getBoostrapModalVersion() {
        return $.fn.modal.Constructor.VERSION;
    }

    return {
        hasBootStrapJs: hasBootStrapJs,
        getBootStrapJsVersionSyncMode: getBootStrapJsVersionSyncMode,
        getBootStrapJsVersionAsyncMode: getBootStrapJsVersionAsyncMode
    }
}();

console.log(myBootstrapUtils.hasBootStrapJs());
console.log(myBootstrapUtils.getBootStrapJsVersionSyncMode());
//myBootstrapUtils.exampleAsyncMode();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also consider checking for `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I have an API that has bootstrap render mode and needs to determine the major bootstrap version. I'm facing many occurences of implementators using only the Bootstrap CSS and not the javascript. I therefore hacked together following function which, altough not perfect and clean at all, helps me detect what version of bootstrap CSS is referenced (if any)

```
    function getBoostrapMajorVersion() {
        try {
            return Number(window['jQuery'].fn.tooltip.Constructor.VERSION.substring(0, 1));
        } catch (e) { }

        var testElement = document.createElement('div');
        testElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute;opacity:0.001;');
        testElement.innerHTML = '<div style="display:block;" class="w-50 h-25"></div>';
        document.body.appendChild(testElement);

        if (testElement.childNodes[0].clientHeight == 25 && testElement.childNodes[0].clientWidth == 50) {
            document.body.removeChild(testElement);
            return 4;
        }

        testElement.innerHTML = ''
        testElement.setAttribute('class', 'hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg');
        if (testElement.clientHeight == 0) {
            document.body.removeChild(testElement);
            return 3;
        }
    }
```